# Score for question looks different than for answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, score

I  notice the font for question score seems to scale when it is 4 digits to fit rather than wrap. Same doesn't happen for answer though.

Noticed this on question [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?newsletter=1&nlcode=125916%7c46d2)

<kbd>[image: Edited screenshot of problem]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in the next update, for some reason the answer vote container included some extra padding which was messing up the automatic text resizing and causing it to go back to the default text size. Thanks for reporting this!