# Weird display bug with favorite question count in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I was going over the SE meta with my phone and I came across this bug.

[image]

Here it looks like the question has a score of -23.

[image]

But it has a score of -2 and 3 people favorited it.

This is really annoying. Can it be fixed?

I have version 1.0.83 (latest) on LG spirit G4 device.

Comment: The question really has 23 downvotes, and nobody favorited it. I can't reproduce, looking fine for me in the app. What device you have? What app version? You can see it in the "About" screen, latest version afaik is 1.0.83

Comment: SE Android app doesn't show favorite count. It's "-23" but wrapped to two lines for whatever reason. Also, no repro on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.83 (beta). Seeing the custom font on the tags, I somewhat believe your Android device overwrites the font property (i.e. font size) that made this happen. AFAIK, [this happened before, but had been fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240697/), thus my conclusion on the system overwritting the font size... or your device screen is too small (though I doubt it, since it's similar to Nexus 4).

Comment: I have version 1.0.83 on the LG spirit G4